# Validate data from CakePHP form with jQuery (AJAX)

Tags: validation, cakephp, forms

I would like to validate both single field and multiple field data from a CakePHP form.
The single field validation should be done on blur from each field while the multiple field validation should be done on submitting the form.

I would like to use the `$validate` property declared in the Model for validating data and I would like to display the errors near each field (single field validation) and on top of the form (for multiple field validation).

My main goal is to achieve this the most "caky" way (if there is one for validating data with jQuery). I couldn't find any useful advice out there and I'm asking you for some help to get this going.

One of my concerns is how shall I pass data from the form to jQuery and then to the action that does the validation and also how shall I return and display the errors, if there are any.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know how to start...I mean I thought of grabbing the data from a field with jQuery, sending it to a controller's action (don't know whether it should be global or controller-specific), validate, and return the results back to the main form. But I don't know exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I coded my own solution to this, but I am still waiting for a more "caky" approach.

I made two generic jQuery functions, one for single field validation and one for multiple field validation. The function should grab the data from the specified form and send it to the form's action via AJAX, to a specially created controller method which will attempt to validate data and output an AJAX response (`""` for validation has passed and `errors` for errors in validation). Then, the result is checked in the jQuery function and the default form behaviour is triggered only if the validation has passed. Otherwise, display the errors and `return false;` to prevent default submission.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest first making sure everything works without jQuery, then use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit your forms via AJAX. If you include the RequestHandler component in your AppController, you should find that your controllers distinguish automatically between AJAX and synchronous requests.

Comment: Everything works in raw PHP. OK, so I use Cake's RequestHandler to check whether the data came from an AJAX request or from a normal one. Then what? And also, **how** do I send data from the form to the controller? I mean, is there a simple way to simply pass the `$this->data` array from the form to the controller using jQuery?

Comment: This is what the jQuery form plugin does. You need to download it from the web site (link above), and follow the examples there.

Comment: I looked at the examples but couldn't find any suitable solution to my problem. I am currently implementing my own solution, hope I'll find a way to get it doing what I need to.

Comment: I manage to code something that works fine, but I am still waiting for a more "caky" approach to this, if any exists.

Comment: Good luck. If you find a really good solution that you're happy with, please post the details here!